# Grunt dynamic variable issue (undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I've got a scoping issue in my grunt file, I require a counter variable to go up each new time grunt.task.run completes, at the minute I can only use asp_files[0] every time, however my desire is to go through each asp/html file stored in an array and then perform my various grunt tasks on that file (already have the boilerplate code for this working, I just cannot get my index variable to change)

heres how I call my grunt modules

```
for (var x = 0; x < asp_files.length; x++){

    grunt.task.run ( [
        //'clean:build',
        'copy:build',
        'replace:gather',
        'uglify:js',
    ]);

}
```

Heres my copy module

```
copy: {
       build: {
            files: [
                {
                    dest: 'build/copied',
                    expand: true,
                    src:  'html/'+asp_files['<%= counterVar %>'] 
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

And here is where counter should be incremented

```
replace: {
            gather: {
                files: [
                    {
                        dest: 'build',
                        expand: true,
                        // This doesn't work, however asp_files[0] works fine, as does asp_files[globalCount] however it never actually increments past 0..
                        src:  'html/'+asp_files['<%= counterVar %>'] 
                    }
                ],
                options: {
                    patterns: [
                        {
                           //Grab the <!--build-js-start--> and <!--build-js-end--> comments and everything in-between
                            match: /\<\!\-\-build\-js\-start[\s\S]*build\-js\-end\-\-\>/,

                            replacement: function ( matchedString ) {

                                js_filename = file_names[globalCount];

                                grunt.config( 'counter', globalCount );
                                globalCount++;
                                var count = grunt.config('counter');

                                // This prints out the count correctly...
                                console.log("The config counter value is: "+count);
```

I've tried many different ways to try and get a counter or any sort of variable to change through each build however to no avail

What am I doing wrong for my counterVar to never change outside of my replace:gather module?    (  Heres full working source if needed: http://pastebin.com/F1cdSeB4 )

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the Grunt way is to look at the problem from another point of view: list all your files and ask each task to work on all of them (instead of running all tasks on 1 file):

```
var aspFiles = ['html/file1.asp', 'html/file2.asp'];
//...
grunt.initConfig({
  copy: {
    build: {
      files: [{
        dest: 'build/copied',
        expand: true,
        src: aspFiles
      }]
    }
  },
  replace: {
    gather: {
      files: [{
        dest: 'build',
        expand: true,
        src: aspFiles 
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, This solution is simple kicking myself for not seeing this. I still have an issue though in that I need my uglify to run after each time the jsResources[] is calculated. At the minute I cannot get it to output 3 seperate files, only a single file .js with the 3 items in the filename array concated together. How would I get uglify to run with the new set of javascript files for each asp/html file?

Comment: I'll need more details - what is jsResources? Why do you want 3 uglified files instead of one (faster)? Is your list of files fixed or variable?

Comment: Ok great, so basically each asp/html file has an array of .js files (jsResources[]), for example when reading myexample.asp this array might contain "js/file1.js, js/file2.js". Now I would like uglify to concat these files and output the .js file as "myexample.js". Currently if I provide uglify an array of my filenames it just creates a js file "index,page1,page2.js" instead of 3 seperate files containing just the js used for that page. I hope you can follow that let me know if I need to elaborate further on anything.

Comment: I think the issue lies in that uglify is not getting run until all of my asp_files have been evaluated and added to JsResources[], however each new file that is checked wipes the previous contents of the array. I need a way in which for uglify to get called immedietely after determining the js files used for each html/asp file, is this possible?

Comment: OK, looked at your bin, got it. I believe you would be better served uglifying everything in a single js file (better caching, less network calls, easier build process) - but I'm adding another answer on how to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `grunt.task.run` does not actually run the task, it just adds it to the stack of tasks to run **once the current one is done**. So basically your counter variable is set to its last value, and the same task is run N times. More globally, never reuse a javascript variable from outside your task (like jsResources) - turn it into a unique immutable variable (like, an array of filenames to jsResources - jsResources[path] = [...]).

So to get what you want you need to create N different targets in your loop and add these to the run stack - for example:

```
for (var x = 0; x < asp_files.length; x++){
  // we create targets copy:build0, copy:build1, etc.
  var target = 'copy:build'+x;
  grunt.config(target, {
    files: [{
      dest: 'build/copied',
      expand: true,
      src:  'html/'+asp_files[x] 
    }]
  });
  // then queue them for running
  grunt.task.run ([
    // copy:build0
    target
  ]);
}
```

You need to extend to do the same for all the tasks you want to run in that way (uglify).